# change size of viewcontroller - iphone sdk

Tags: ios4

I am using custom tabbar and navigation controller. When i add any subview it works fine but when I try to push a view of what ever size it automatically changes its size to full screen and overlaps the tabbar.

```
couponDetailsVC *myVC = [[couponDetailsVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"couponDetailsVC" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
        //[self.view addSubview:myVC.view];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:myVC animated:YES];
```

Can anyone please tell me how to resize the viewcontroller I also tried the following but no success:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

CGSize size = {320, 300}; // size of view in popover
self.contentSizeForViewInPopover = size;

[super viewWillAppear:animated];

}
```

Also tried the above in viewDidLoad

Also tried changing the size of view controller after pushing it like:

```
myVC.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 411);
```

How to achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

If the ViewController's view is overlapping your tabbar, perhaps you are not following the correct view hierarchy. TabBar controller is a container controller that would 'contain' UIViewControllers' views. Generally UIViewControllers' views are intended to be shown in full screen only.

Comment: hmm so do you mean there is no way to push a viewcontoller's view which has height less than its original height?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this snippet will solve your issue..

```
myVC.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

myVC.view.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
```